# Complex data charts React-Native

Tags: react-native, charts

It is necessary to display the following charts (see photo). The first: separates the stages by color and height, the graph displays the duration of the stages and their sequence. Second: the graph displays the sequence, the duration of the stages on a certain day of the week, the color indicates the stage. What library can use to implement these graphs?

Thank you!

[First](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EI3J.png)

[Second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kSec.png)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! A few libraries - https://github.com/recharts/recharts, https://github.com/jerairrest/react-chartjs-2, https://github.com/FormidableLabs/victory. These should be able to get you own your way.

Comment: Thank you! Victory - nice lib!